# Independence and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

So, it's pretty clear that for independent $X,Y\in L_1(P)$ (with $E(X|Y)=E(X|\sigma(Y))$), we have $E(X|Y)=E(X)$. It is also quite easy to construct an example (for instance, $X=Y=1$) which shows that $E(X|Y)=E(X)$, does not imply independence of $X$ and $Y$.

However, since $X,Y$ are independent iff $E(f(X)g(Y))=E(f(X))E(g(Y))$ for all bounded Borel functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, does it not make sense that $X$ and $Y$ are independent iff $E(f(X)|Y)=E(f(X))$, again for all bounded Borel functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$?

Clearly, one of the implications hold (since $f(X)$ will be independent of $Y$), but what about the other way around? Am I completely wrong in my assessment?

Comment: Indeed "E(X|Y)=E(X), does not imply independence of X and Y" but the case when X=Y=1 with full probability is not a counterexample since constant random variables are iundependent of everything.

Answer (score 17):

Assume that ${\rm E}[h(X)\mid Y]={\rm E}[h(X)]$ holds for any bounded Borel-measurable function $h$ and let $f,g$ be bounded Borel-measurable functions. Then
$$
\begin{align}
{\rm E}[f(X)g(Y)]&={\rm E}[{\rm E}[f(X)g(Y)\mid Y]]={\rm E}[g(Y){\rm E}[f(X)\mid Y]]\\
&={\rm E}[g(Y){\rm E}[f(X)]]={\rm E}[g(Y)]{\rm E}[f(X)]
\end{align}
$$
which shows that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: why is $E[X|Y] = E[X]$ not enough for independance ? From that previous statement, one could build up (with monotone class theorem) your theorem... I don't understand how yours can be true while mine is not.

Comment: @Marine Galantin How would you do that?

Comment: oh wait... I got confused. It is actually that I had on mind : $$ P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y) \iff E( 1_X 1_Y ) = E(1_X) E(1_Y) $$ Yielding your theorem. Sorry ! In fact, your theorem is equivalent to $$P(X | Y ) = P(X) \iff X,Y \text{ independant}$$