# Is "Covariance is 0" equivalent to "Conditional Expectation equals Unconditional Expectation"?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, covariance

In formulas:
\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y)=0 \quad \Leftrightarrow\quad \mathbb{E}[Y|X]=\mathbb{E}[Y]
\end{align}
is this true?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is - I mean if I actually would have expected an answer from someone else I would maybe have put more effort into it but it was just a question I couldn't find an answer to when looking so I thought I would post the answer I found since this seems like something that someone else might think about as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only "$\Leftarrow$" is true:

\begin{align}
Cov(X,Y)&=\mathbb{E}[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])] \\
&=\mathbb{E}[XY]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[XY|X]]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[X\mathbb{E}[Y]]-\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]\\
&=0
\end{align}

While "$\Rightarrow$" is false in general:

Be $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y:=|X|$ then $\mathbb{E}[X|Y]=0$ which implies that $Cov(X,Y)=0$ as shown above. But $\mathbb{E}[Y|X]=Y$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/376087/445105